# What does this connector symbol mean in a charger schematic?

Tags: connector, usb-pd

Could somebody explain what symbol JP1 means? iIt is presented in the schematic of the [datasheet](https://www.hynetek.com/uploadfiles/site/219/news/d45ab9c8-5dd6-46d5-8572-95e337dd3467.pdf) of a USB-C PD controller. I think JP1 symbol is kind of two state connector (normally closed and normally open) used for testing given that in the datasheet of the component it is not specified as required.

[image]

Comment: JP is short for jumper (no pun intended).

Comment: uriously similar to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688339/what-is-this-weird-split-circle-symbol-in-a-schematic/688358#688358 from yesterday

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]That is (probably) a three pin post header with a 2 pin shorting cap that allows you to select either an external source or the signal through R24 as an interrupt source.

Comment: do you know how could I look for an example of specific component? I could not get the symbol in connectors libraries of different ECAD softwares

Comment: @imt_blake For designing a board in a CAD program, you can just use a 1x3 2.54mm pin header. Every CAD program should have those.

Answer (score 6):

This symbol is a 3-pin jumper (hence the JP# reference). Here's KiCad's part selection dialog with the Jumper_3_Bridged12 (Jumper, 3-pole, pins 1+2 closed/bridged) part selected. The side with the arc marks the "default" connection.

[image: KiCad part selection dialog jumper]

This is usually reflected in the layout with a 3-pin straight header footprint. It allows manual connection of the central pin to one of the outer pins and is very common for selecting the origin of Vcc like in that schematic.

[image: Jumper]

It also used to be common for selecting options in old motherboards, where a connection or disconnection would set a bit to 0 or 1.

[image: Jumpers for multiple selections]

One common form, for which some people use the same symbol, is the *solder jumper*. This is actually made from a pure PCB footprint where the default is pre-connected through a small trace that can be cut with a knife. Then the connection can be done in the other side (or re-made in the first side) with a big solder ball. The image below shows KiCad's symbol for the solder jumper, but the

[image: KiCad part selection dialog solder jumper]

[image: Solder jumper layout example]

Finally, here are some other examples of solder jumpers (most of these are 2-pin only):

[image: Solder jumper example 1]
[image: Solder jumper example 2]
[image: Solder jumper example 3]

Answer (score 4):

Select jumper. It's a 3-pin SIP header with a shorting cap that fits over two of them so you can connect PULL UP to Ext or R24 by moving it from one position to the other.

Answer (score 4):

That is a 3-pin jumper block to allow selecting from where the pull-up for the chip interrupt signal comes.

But this is a schematic of a reference design which doubles as an evaluation board for all customers that might use the chip enable pin in different ways, so there must be a signal selection jumper to choose how the board works and how the chip is used.

If you have no use for selecting the pull-up, if you always use only one anyway,  you don't need the jumper.

Unless you are making a replica of the eval board for some reason.